# How to give a DHCP server priority over another server

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp-server

We have a router that is also functioning as a DHCP server.  However, it does not offer much configuration and so as a result it always offers IPv6 as well as IPv4 DNS servers, which breaks some devices being able to see some servers on the LAN which require a DNS override to return a local address instead of the world visible address.

One possible workaround we are considering is to set up a DHCP server on one of these servers.  If the server is up, then it would send DHCP replies which are set up properly with regards to what DNS servers are to be used.   We could only run this DHCP server, however if this machine goes down for whatever reason, then it seems like everything would go down, because no other DHCP servers would be around to pick up the slack.  But if we run the DHCP server as a backup (as it rarely if ever goes down) then we need to somehow give it a lower priority so that it doesn't hand out addresses unless the other server doesn't reply or is down.

How can we do this?

Comment: As the answer states, this isn't possible. Are you referring to a Comcast modem/router? IPv6 DNS entries show up for other reasons than DHCP. IPv6 is able to auto-configure using mechanisms other than DHCP. The proper solution to this problem is to segregate the problematic router from the rest of the network by putting it in to bridge mode, and putting a more capable router behind it, or replacing the problematic router if it isn't an ISP device.

Comment: see also this canonical answer: https://serverfault.com/q/368512/182307

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the DHCP protocol does not provide a way to do this.

The DHCP RFC says that if a client receives multiple DHCP OFFERs (e.g. from multiple servers), the client gets to decide which OFFER it accepts. But it leaves that selection algorithm as an implementation detail for the DHCP client implementers.

I know Apple's DHCP client (in macOS, iOS, watchOS, tvOS, HomePod, etc.) has a heuristic to select whichever OFFER contains more DHCP Options, under the surprisingly reliable assumption that "real" corporate DHCP servers are more likely to be configured to serve out lots of extra DHCP options (like lists of LDAP and WINS servers to use), whereas some random embedded DHCP server in some consumer home network device will have a much shorter list of DHCP Options (like a Wi-Fi home gateway router that accidentally got plugged into the corporate LAN).

I can't speak for the DHCP OFFER selection algorithms in other DHCP client implementations such as Windows, or Android or other Linuxes, etc.  It could be that many DHCP client implementations on your network will just select the first OFFER they see, or the last offer they see after listening for X milliseconds. There's really no way to know. You could peruse the sources for the popular open source DHCP client implementations, but I doubt there's a way to find out what various versions of the Windows DHCP client does, unless Microsoft has happened to document it publicly somewhere.